# Cannot start redmine on ubuntu 10.4

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, redmine

When I try to start redmine 1.1.3 I get this error:
`Missing the i18n 0.4.2 gem. Please 'gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n'`

However if I do `sudo gem list` I get:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
i18n (0.4.2)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.7)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with not finding i18n in the gempath when the application actually runs.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to remedy this?

I can add that I'm using passenger to run redmine. Though I get this error by using `./script/server` as well.

---

I've gotten past this error now (turns out only root could read the gems, chmod a+r solved it) but now instead I get this error:

```
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] /var/www/redmine/public/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] /var/www/redmine/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/../config/environment.rb:20
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.cgi:3:in `require'
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] \tfrom /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.cgi:3
[Sun May 29 18:40:55 2011] [error] [client 98.210.156.61] Premature end of script headers: dispatch.cgi
```

I have `RailsEnv production` in my virtual host but it doesn't seem to work. If I do `./script/server -e production` it works. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You have to decide whether you want to use passenger or CGI. The stack trace indicates the CGI variant. See the documentation on http://modrails.com on how to properly setup passenger.

Comment: Yeah, I had accidentally used cgi and passenger which caused errors later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was a permission problem. Solved by doing `chmod -R a+rx /usr/lib/ruby`

The second problem was that passenger wasn't running, I had a typo in my passenger.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround: http://www.redmine.org/issues/7796#note-15

Comment: I've tried that already, sadly it does not work. This is what led me to believe it's a path issue.

Comment: Please give us the output of `gem env`? Did you check the rubys directory in the GEM PATHS to make sure the i18n-0.4.2 exist?

Comment: Turns out it was a permission problem, only root could read those gems.